# Checking "never seen" values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES 5.X for indexing syslog messages with a Timestamp.
At the end of the day I need to make a query to know, for a given field, which values are never seen before in my index history.

Any ideas how to achive this goal in an efficient way?

As an example,

Suppose in date 2017/06/19 the following document has been indexed:

`{
  "text":  "hello",
  "date":  "2017/06/19"
}`

Now, in date 2017/06/20 the following documents has been indexed:

`{
  "text":  "hello",
  "date":  "2017/06/20"
}`

`{
  "text":  "world",
  "date":  "2017/06/20"
}`

`{
  "text":  "from",
  "date":  "2017/06/20"
}`

`{
  "text":  "Europe",
  "date":  "2017/06/20"
}`

At 23:59 of 2017/06/20 I want to know which new values for `text` field has been discovered today. I'm wondering if is there any better solution than take each single value and query the text field with a range filter.

The query should return "world", "from", "Europe".

Comment: Can you provide some concrete example? Do you mean numeric values, string values, dates?

Comment: I have edited my question ;)